# Guidance about placing labels in the center of the sector in donut chart

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have taken this Latex code of donut/pie chart from the internet. I have modified according to my requirement. Somehow, I couldn't manage to put the labels into the center of sectors in the donut chart. I have tried to modify `\draw` node command but it did not place label into the center of sectors. It's because my Tikz skill and Latex skills are not advanced. I would also be grateful if you could guide me to put another label say Sector 5 into the donut chart hole and provide color for it. Thanks a lot in advanced.

Following is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\innerradius{1.0cm}
\def\outerradius{2.2cm}

%%%%% Donut chart macro %%%%%%
\newcommand{\donutchart}[1]{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0} \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
    \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}
    \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the chart
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}

  % Rotate so we start from the top
  \begin{scope}[rotate=90]

  % Loop through each value set.cumnum keeps track of where we are in the chart
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
  \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}

        % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}

        % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
        \fill[\colour] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius) --
        (-\newcumnum:\innerradius) arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius) -- cycle;

        % Draw the labels for sector
        \draw  node [text=black, font=\bfseries] at (\midangle:\innerradius+ 1ex) {\name};

        % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
        \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
    }

  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

 \donutchart{26/cyan/Sector1,  28/orange/Sector2, 33.5/yellow/Sector3, 12.5/red/Sector4}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result of my code:

[image]

Comment: Next command will center sector labels: `\draw  node [text=black, font=\bfseries] at (\midangle:{\innerradius+\wheelwidth/2}) {\name};`

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks. I appreciate that. I am trying to fill the color in the entire donut hole. I tried this:    \node[circle, scale=\innerradius/5, fill = lightgray!15]{};  I use that 5 because if I was taking whole innerradius for scale it was filling filling area larger than donut chart. It's working but I am looking for better way.

Comment: No need for `node`, a `circle` will do the job. Insert `\fill[lightgray!15] circle (\innerradius);` before `\draw node[text=black,...` otherwise part of nodes text will be covered by new circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy if you just calculate the center of the radii. But if you do not rotate the text it still looks strange, although it would be really centered.

For more details have a look at the added comments to the code.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

    \def\innerradius{1.0cm}
    \def\outerradius{2.2cm}
    % add a command to compute the center of the radii
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\centerradius}{(\outerradius + \innerradius)/2}

    %%%%% Donut chart macro %%%%%%
    \newcommand{\donutchart}[1]{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0} \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
            \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}
            \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult
        }
        \begin{tikzpicture}

            % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the chart
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}

            % Rotate so we start from the top
            \begin{scope}[rotate=90]

                % Loop through each value set.cumnum keeps track of where we are in the chart
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
                \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}

                    % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}

                    % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
                    \fill[\colour] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius) --
                    (-\newcumnum:\innerradius) arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius) -- cycle;

                    % Draw the labels for sector
                    \node [
                        text=black,
                        font=\bfseries,
                        % rotate the text so it can be better seen that it
                        % is really in the center
                        rotate=\midangle,
%                        draw=green,
                    ] at (\midangle:\centerradius) {\name};
                    % for debugging purposes only
                    \draw  node [circle,fill=green,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt] at (\midangle:\centerradius) {};

                    % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
                    \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
                }

            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

\begin{document}

 \donutchart{26/cyan/Sector1,  28/orange/Sector2, 33.5/yellow/Sector3, 12.5/red/Sector4}

\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks. It is in Center but it looks strange since it's not horizontal. I am thinking to put in the center position but horizontal as shown in my chart image above.